# cherry-picking a merged PR on github

Tags: git, github

I've recently came across cherry-picking in Github/git. I've a merged PR with a single commit and I want to cherry-pick that commit to raise another PR. Is it possible on Github using git?

Comment: [not via the UI](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/629). It is possible using Git locally, then opening a new PR. Would that be ok for you?

Comment: @DaemonPainter yes, doing it via Git would be fine. Can you please tell me method of cherry picking merged PR? Since I only want the additions/deletions done by that PR

Comment: your merged PR generated a commit. Identify that commit, get on a new branch and run git cherry-pick that_commit. Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626754/git-cherry-pick-syntax-and-merge-branches/12628579) helping?