# How to rebase (cherry-pick) multiple commits with different number of parents in git?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I want to rebase some commits from master branch to another orphaned branch. The history of the repo is quite messy and the master branch has commits with 1 or 2 parents.

If I try to do rebase: `git rebase --onto orphan commit1 commit2` - the git attempts to rebase some misty commits that are not on the range from `commit1` to `commit2`, and as a result a lot of conflicts.

If I try to do cherry-pick: `git cherry-pick commit1..commit2` - then I get error:

```
Commit xxx is a merge but no -m option was given.
```

Or otherwise: `git cherry-pick -m1 commit1..commit2` - I get:

```
Mainline was specified but commit yyy is not a merge.
```

Is there a simple way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Did you try interactive rebase?

Comment: @jonderry Never used it, but if you suggest that this thing will automatically resolve my problem, I will give it a try. But `interactive` makes me think that it's not automatic...

Comment: You will see a list of commits that will be applied, and you can edit the list as you see fit. If you don't have a huge number of commits to apply, you might find it manageable.

Comment: @jonderry There are hundreds and I want them all at once.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229301/git-cherry-pick-says-38c74d-is-a-merge-but-no-m-option-was-given

Comment: Try my answer to [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576291/how-to-squash-all-merges-in-a-branch/27514988#27514988)