# How to squash all merges in a branch?

Tags: git, branch, squash

I have a branch like this:

```
A---B---B1---B2---D---E---E1---E2---G---H
     \           /     \           /
      C1---C2---’       F1---F2---’
```

I want to rewrite it and make it like this:

```
A---B---B1---B2---D---E---E1---E2---G---H
```

That means, squashing all merges.

The branch is very long. How can this be done automatically?

**Edit**

This is not a history linearization. I want to squash all merges, like D and G.

Comment: While it's kinda lame and incredible hacky, you *could* push this history into a svn repository which does exactly that. Afterwards you could remove the svn information.

Comment: It's not just hacky, it also requires to have SVN server installed.

Comment: Jeah, it's not a good solution, I just wanted to mention it for completeness sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. Since we are cherry picking the commit message, author, and author date will be the same as the original commits, including the merges.

Alternatively, you can get the commit message and authorship information from the last commit to the branch before the merge, i.e., the merge's second parent, by adding the following line to the first condition:

```
git commit --amend -C $(git rev-parse $rev^2)
```

These commands can easily converted to a script if you do this often.

Checkout base commit (in detached state):

```
git checkout A~0
```

Cherry pick all commits:

```
for rev in $(git rev-list  HEAD..branch-name --first-parent --reverse)
do
    if [[ $(git show --summary --format="%P" $rev | wc -w ) -gt 1 ]]
    then
        git cherry-pick $rev --mainline 1
        # git commit --amend -C $(git rev-parse $rev^2)
    else
        git cherry-pick $rev
    fi
done
```

Force old branch and checkout:

```
git branch -f branch-name HEAD
git checkout branch-name
```

Comment: Can you clarify what it means to "removing adding modifying the first condition"? Where do I put that `git commit --amend` and when would I want to use that?

Comment: @Robru I fixed it up a bit. I must have changed it without proofreading, so it did not  make any sense. It should be clearer now.