# Cherry pick shows no -m option was given error

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I have two branch master and development

I need to get some commit id from development branch in master branch so I do it by cherry-pick but it shows me some error

```
$> git cherry-pick cf0d52b

error: Commit cf0d52b900f990300c3aa17936ddbae1476d461a is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

I am not getting this error, why this error comes and how will I get rid of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git cherry-pick says "...38c74d is a merge but no -m option was given"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229301/git-cherry-pick-says-38c74d-is-a-merge-but-no-m-option-was-given)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You are trying to `cherry-pick` a merge. A merge is build up from at several parents. You have to supply the parent id to the merge.

You have to supply any of the followings:

> ***`-m parent-number`*** / ***`--mainline parent-number`***
>
> Usually you cannot cherry-pick a merge because **you do not know which side of the merge** should be considered the mainline.
>
> This option specifies the parent number (starting from 1) of the mainline and allows cherry-pick to replay the change relative to the specified parent.

---

#### How to find out what are the commit parents?

Use the `git show` command to view the commit parents and then you can choose the parent index or the SHA-1

[image]

Comment: I still don't get how to find the parent number

Comment: In the screenshot above there are 2 ids, d684a65 and d23e8e8, how to know which one refers to the branch I am on?

Comment: In addition to @RaphaelPinel's answer, you can check the git log and check which branch holds the commit you want to cherry-pick. That commit should have one of the ID:s displayed under "Merge: ".
Typically the command will then be:
```git cherry-pick -m 1 <SHA>```

Comment: In addition to @RaphaelPinel and @MikaelHalen, ```git log --no-merges```  would be used to display commits without "merge hash"; for projects with along numbers of changes or merges this could be useful

Comment: @Raphael Pinel the first parent is the first hash (in this case, d684a65). This hash is the "parent" hash on which d23e808 was merged. 

Or, commit 5717a50 is the "merged" result of merging d23e808 (parent 2) into d684a65 (parent 1.)

Answer (score 11):

> This option specifies the parent number (starting from 1)

Up until Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), that number could be 0! (which is incorrect)

See [commit b16a991](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b16a991c1be5681b4b673d4343dfcc0c2f5ad498) (15 Mar 2017) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9c96637](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c96637163ef26c7726e693984c2d4d9599d4e7e), 17 Mar 2017)</sup>

> ### `cherry-pick`: detect bogus arguments to `--mainline`
>
> The cherry-pick and revert commands use `OPT_INTEGER()` to parse `--mainline`. The stock parser is smart enough to reject non-numeric nonsense, but it doesn't know that parent counting starts at 1.
>
> Worse, the value "0" is indistinguishable from the unset case, so a user who assumes the counting is 0-based will get a confusing message:
>
> ```
> $ git cherry-pick -m 0 $merge
>   error: commit ... is a merge but no -m option was given.
> ```
>
> The correct diagnosis is that "`-m 0`" does not refer to the first parent ("`-m 1`" does).

Comment: Yes, I'm using `git version 2.21.0` and `-m 1` works.

Answer (score 3):

Just as the Error suggest. You  try to pick a merge commit, so you have tell git against which parent it should produce the diff that is then applied to the target.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `git log --no-merges`  would be used to only display commits without "merge hash". For projects with along numbers of changes or merges this could be useful