# Visual Studio - unable to Create cherry Pick from grey commit in the graph

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, cherry-pick

In Visual Studio, I can pull latest from my source branch.

From the history graph, I can see all the commits.

From the "train track" graph, the nodes are colored, most are blue circles, but I have a few that are gray.

If I right-click on an entry that is blue, I can select the option to perform a cherry pick, but not when it's gray.

Why is this - what does "gray" signify?

Comment: We can only do `cherry-pick` from other branch commits not from the `current` one. Is the `gray` line from your `current` branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Git graph experience](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/announcing-git-graph-and-advanced-filters-to-visualize-commit-history/):

- The blue dots represent any commit in the repo or a file
- The **grey dots** represent a merge commit.
- A line connects a commit to its ancestor commit. In case a commit
  does not show its parent within the next 50 commits, you will see an
  arrow that once clicked will connect the commit to its parent commit.

From the [git-cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt---mainlineparent-number) doc:

> Usually you cannot cherry-pick a merge because you do not know which
> side of the merge should be considered the mainline. This option
> specifies the parent number (starting from 1) of the mainline and
> allows cherry-pick to replay the change relative to the specified
> parent.

You can also refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229301/git-cherry-pick-says-38c74d-is-a-merge-but-no-m-option-was-given) for more info.

Comment: In my case it was because I still had uncommitted changes .. took me 10 minutes to figure that out :D