# Merge a commit from a branch in repositoryA to a branch in repositoryB

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch, git-repo

Assuming I have two repositories called `repositoryA` and `repositoryB`. I need to merge a commit `abcdefgh` which is in a branch in `repositoryA` and called `branchA` to another branch called `branchB` and located in `repositoryB`.

in repositoryB:

```
git checkout -b branchB
git remote add repositoryA git@github.com:xxx/repositoryA.git
git remote update
git cherry-pick abcdefgh
```

This doesn't work, when I merge, it merges the entire branchA to branchB and makes a lot of conflicts and cherry-pick and above it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two steps as you mentioned are good! But then instead of

```
git remote update
```

do

```
git fetch repositoryA branchA
```

and then you can cherry pick

```
git cherry-pick abcdefgh
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I get this error `error: commit abcdefgh is a merge but no -m option was given.`

Comment: @schedulingqs inside `branchA` from `repositoryA` can you do `git log` and then take the commit hash. Then try to `git cherry-pick [commit-hash]` which will look something like `git cherry-pick a4ab52a`

Comment: @schedulingqs see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229393/2008111 (looks like you are not trying to cherry-pick a single commit but a merge-commit)

Comment: `git remote update` runs `git fetch` on *all* remotes by default (same as `git fetch --all`), so that doesn't explain anything. I think the OP must have run `git merge abcdefgh` instead of `git cherry-pick abcdefgh` originally.