# git cherrypicking with merged commits

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I haven't use cherry-picking that much in the past, but I need to use it today. So far the commits are linear so I got no problem

But what happen in the following situation

[image]

I want to cherry pick all the commits from 1 to 7. But from commit 3 to 5 there was a merge (not fast forward)

I want to reproduce this in another branch (main for example)

Can I just cherry pick normally  1,2,3,4,5,6,7

or should I do 1,2,3,4,7,5,6?

Comment: Please include what the final expected branch should look like.

Comment: You say "1 to 7" but then continue to explain you want "1,2,3,4,5,6,7". Looking at your picture "1 to 7" is "1,2,3,7"

Comment: It should look the same but over another branch

Comment: @knittl at commit 3 I added two different commits 4 and 7 but divergent. commit 5 merged both

Comment: If you want to transplant the whole thing somewhere, a rebase may be more helpful. Other tips including "simplify (123476)", "use merge instead": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229301/git-cherry-pick-says-38c74d-is-a-merge-but-no-m-option-was-given

Comment: "I want to cherry pick all the commits from 1 to 7" That's called a _rebase_. And it will handle the merge commit for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783599/rebasing-a-git-merge-commit