# Switch on another branch (create if not exists), without checking if already exists?

Tags: git, branch

`git checkout -b foo` switches on `foo` branch (even if it doesn't exist, it is created), but if the `foo` branch already exists it throws an error like this:

```
fatal: A branch named 'foo' already exists.
```

What's the command that does the following check?

- if the branch already exists, just switch on it (`git checkout foo`)
- if the branch doesn't exist, create it and switch on it (`git checkout -b foo`)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Update Q3 2019 (Git 2.23): there now actually is a [`git switch` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)!

```
git switch -c aBranch
```

Or, if the branch already exists:

```
git switch aBranch
```

As I [explained in 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003030/what-is-the-git-restore-command-and-what-is-the-difference-between-git-restor#comment115524702_58003889), the `git switch` command is "[experimental](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e43b7ff1ea4b6f16b93a432b6718e9ab38749bd)" in name only, and is here to stay.

You would need an alias though, which tries *first* to switch to the existing branch and, if it fails (because the branch might actually *not* exist), creates it:

```
switchoc = "!f() { git switch $1 2>/dev/null || git switch -c $1; }; f"
```

Note the name of the alias: switchoc (for "switch or create").

That combination `git switch`+`git switch -c` does *precisely* what the OP is asking for.

As [`jar`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3647970/jar) pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961371/switch-on-another-branch-create-if-not-exists-without-checking-if-already-exi/26961416#comment117178534_26961416):

> Anyone trying this in 2021, note that **you cannot shadow existing `git` commands with aliases**.
> Since `git switch` is a `git` command, this alias (named "`switch`") won't work. You must create your unique name for the alias, like "`switchit`" or something.

---

[bgusach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394590/bgusach)'s alias mentioned below in the comment is safer (based on [Jiří Pavelka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5611007/ji%C5%99%C3%AD-pavelka) 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35683029/6309)):

```
switch = "!f() { git checkout $1 2>/dev/null || git checkout -b $1; }; f"

git switch abranch
```

---

Original answer (2014) You can try:

```
git checkout -B foo
```

From [`git checkout` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

> If `-B` is given, `<new_branch>` is created if it doesn’t exist; otherwise, it is reset. This is the transactional equivalent of

```
$ git branch -f <branch> [<start point>]
$ git checkout <branch>
```

As mentioned below, use it with caution as it does reset the branch, which is not always desirable.
If you did reset the branch by mistake with this command, [you can easily revert to its previous state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2531803/6309) with:

```
git reset HEAD@{1}
```

---

[Tal Jacob - Sir Jacques](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14427765/tal-jacob-sir-jacques) proposes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961371/switch-on-another-branch-create-if-not-exists-without-checking-if-already-exi/26961416#comment137353950_26961416):

> Configure git alias with:
>
> ```
> git config alias.switchoc '!f() { git switch $1 2>/dev/null || git switch -c $1; }; f'
> ```
>
> Then use with:
>
> ```
> git switchoc <branch>
> ```

Comment: Note that `-B` will _reset_ the branch, see my answer for a (lengthier...) alternative.

Comment: Don't use this. It will more often than not destroy your branch and give you nice headaches bringing it back...

Comment: -1, because the answer is misleading. The behaviour that OP and most readers expect is "if the branch already exists, just switch on it (git checkout foo)". But the first line of code in this answer does a very different thing. Yes, it's explained below, but what people first read and try is this misleading code.

Comment: @jar Very good point, thank you. I have edited the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: This answer is not correct, `git switch -c` will not switch to an already existing branch. If it already exists, it will error out.

Comment: Even `git switch -C` is incorrect, as that will blow away any changes and force that branch to point to HEAD instead of whatever it was pointed at before.

Comment: @Jay Right... so `git switch foo || git switch -c foo`?

Comment: `git switch` is experimental and the answer does not actually do what is asked.

Comment: @silverwind Thank you for your feedback. I have edited the answer to qualify the "experimental" status of `git switch` (in short, no worries, that command is not going anywhere). And to re-affirm that `git switch foo || git switch -c foo` does actually do what is asked. Thank you for helping me to clarify that answer.

Comment: Configure git alias with: `git config alias.switchoc '!f() { git switch $1 2>/dev/null || git switch -c $1; }; f'`
Then use with `git switchoc <branch>`

Comment: @TalJacob-SirJacques Nice, well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 106):

Agreed with ssmith. Had the same problem and `-B` does not solve it, coz of reset. His solution works, however my solution looks simpler:

```
git checkout foo || git checkout -b foo
```

That works for me :)

**EDIT**

Without error output iff foo not exists

```
git checkout foo 2>/dev/null || git checkout -b foo
```

Comment: Ah yes, much simpler and shorter. =) There is however the rather minor caveat that if "foo" exists as something other than a branch (ex: tags) it'll check it out rather than create the branch, but it's a pretty edge case.

Comment: Another minor caveat, if the branch does not exist you get an error in the output. @ssmith solution is cleaner. +1 for simplicity anyway

Comment: @GabrielePetronella simply hide error output, see EDIT

Comment: @JiříPavelka thanks, however in my use case I want the output, but just the one of the successful comment.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella that should be it. You can get success from first command or success/error from the second command.

Comment: @JiříPavelka Oh right, you're redirecting only stderr. Yes thanks, that works :)

Comment: Nice. I made an alias for this... just in case it helps somebody: `switch = "!f() { git checkout $1 2>/dev/null || git checkout -b $1; }; f"`

Comment: be careful: if `foo` matches a file in the repo, this will check out _that file_ and revert changes to it. @ssmith 's answer is a little safer.

Answer (score 31):

Note the rather important fact that `-B` will *reset* an existing branch before checking it out, which I don't believe @Ionica wants according to his question.

I certainly didn't, so the best one-liner I could come up with is this:

`git checkout $(git show-ref --verify --quiet refs/heads/<branch> || echo '-b') <branch>`

This can be made into a handy alias like so:

```
[alias]
  # git cob <branch>
  cob = "!f() { git checkout $(git show-ref --verify --quiet refs/heads/\"$1\" || echo '-b') \"$1\"; }; f"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 26):

The command `checkout -b` creates a new branch and then checks out to that branch. So, if a branch already exists, it cannot create a new one.

Instead you need to do:

```
git checkout -B <branchname>
```

The above command does in a context sensitive way. If there's a branch, it switches, if not, it creates and checkout.

Comment: *it cannot create a new one.* -- I want to handle that.

Comment: " it creates and checkout" …and reset the branch.

Answer (score 4):

Not very different from what George Pavelka suggested, but instead of relying on status of "git checkout ", this checks for the presence and then decides the command to use

```
git show-branch <branch> &>/dev/null && git checkout <branch> || git checkout -b <branch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `git switch foo` (without `-c`).