# How to Revert a Merge commit on Remote branch in Atlassian Stash GIT

Tags: git, version-control, merge, atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-server

I am new to GIT (Atlassian Stash), Using [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) for all the GIT operations. I have merged two branches in GIT using `Merge Branch1 into current branch` option and committed the changed to the branch.

I have learned about `Reset current branch to this commit` but it only work of local branch not for remote branch.

I have tried to `Reverse commit` on the last valid commit but it is showing following error

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false revert
>   --no-edit 7195cc8f27802568becdc09b47effaeb45cc9eeb error: Commit 7195cc8f27802568becdc09b47effaeb45cc9eeb is a merge but no -m option
>   was given. fatal: revert failed

How can i fix the above problem

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your remote branch is your development branch and that no other developers are working in this branch.

If your branch is a shared branch with other people, please ignore my solution.

If your local branch is up to date, you can use the following Git command to update the remote branch:

```
cd your_workspace_path
git push origin your_branch_name --force
```

The --force option will force the update on the remote branch.

Another answer on the same subject:
[Removing/undoing a merge on Sourcetree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537097/removing-undoing-a-merge-on-sourcetree)