# Git: how to revert a revert

Tags: git

This is my current situation.

I have erroneously merged a pull request that contained rubbish.

So I reverted it using `git revert -m 1 <sha of commit>`

Now I wish to undo that revert but **this time cherry pick only the correct** **changes**.

Please how do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: So you don't want to revert the revert, you just want to cherry-pick a few commits into your branch?

Comment: Thanks ROMA, I guess so :-)

Comment: Sounds like you should use `cherry-pick` then ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I "un-revert" a reverted Git commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728093/how-do-i-un-revert-a-reverted-git-commit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git reset` to remove the bad commits (including the revert).

Assuming your history looks like:

```
good -> good -> good -> rubbish -> revertRubbish
```

You can simply do
`git reset HEAD~2` to make your version history look like:

```
good -> good -> good
```

If it's more complicated than that, say

```
good1 -> good2  -> rubbish -> good3 -> good4 -> revertGood4 -> revertGood3 -> revertRubbish
```

You may have to do something like:

```
git reset HEAD~6  //Deletes last 6 commits
git cherry-pick good3
git cherry-pick good4
```

with a resulting history of

```
good1 -> good2  -> good3* -> good4*
```

The asterisks indicate the code changes will be the same, just with a different hash than the original commits.

Comment: Except then you are possibly rewriting public history, which is bad.

Comment: Yes, that is good to note that `git reset` should not be used on public history.  If the OP has caught the problem before it made it into public space, or it is a repo with few contributors, then `git reset` is fine, in my opinion.  Otherwise, OP will just have to be stuck with the messy pull request/revert/cherry-pick in the public history.

Answer (score 4):

Revert in git is a commit too. So you can simply revert a revert as usual commit:

```
git revert <revert_you_want_to_undo_sha1>
```