# I reverted a commit. Now i want it all back

Tags: git, github

Hello i reverted a git commit called "Add user microposts".

I didn't mean to do it. I thought revert ment to go back to this version. But it actually means to get undo everything in that commit.

How do i get it back?

You can see what i did below.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728093/how-do-i-un-revert-a-reverted-git-commit

Comment: `git reset --hard 4a593` -- that moves the checked-out branch label to commit 4a593, which here abandons the two reverts.  They're still in your repo, if you still want to refer to them add a tag or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the commit that you did as a revert is last commit that you have, you can remove that:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

It will delete your last commit and will give the changes back.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is `git cherry-pick 4a593`, assuming that's the hash that corresponds to your original commit. This will re-apply the commit on top of your codebase, undoing the revert.

Answer (score -1):

if you want it back, you can revert the revert

```
git revert <commit>
```