# Remove a commit revert in git

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-revert

In git (I am using tortoiseGit) I have a single branch and I made a commit. This commit is a security patch that modified something like 10 files. When I pushed this commit to my dev site it broke the site. I reverted the commit and worked on other things i.e. made more commits. I now have time to look into this issue more and would like to undo the revert so I can look into the changes more. Can I revert the revert? What would the ramifications of doing this? Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728093/how-do-i-un-revert-a-reverted-git-commit

Answer (score 1):

You can revert the revert, but personally I usually avoid this as it leads to nested `Revert "Revert "...""` commit messages. Instead, you may want to `git cherry-pick` your original commit to re-apply it.