# I accidentally use revert instead of reset uncommitted files

Tags: git

I accidentally use revert instead of reset uncommitted files. What should I do now? I am still new to git. Now I was forced to commit the revert.

Comment: _"Now I was forced to commit the revert."_ - no you weren't, you can still reset to an earlier commit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I "un-revert" a reverted Git commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728093/how-do-i-un-revert-a-reverted-git-commit)

Comment: I have commited the revert -.- how do i proceed from here?

Comment: I've deleted some files and would like to get them back. is it possible with git reset?

$ git reset HEAD
Unstaged changes after reset:
D       config-overrides.js
M       package-lock.json
M       package.json
this is what i get

Comment: AFAIK, uncommitted files aren't recoverable if you overwrote them using git (like checkout, reset, etc)

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ or something similar and hadn't restarted the program, you might still have the files in your local history.

Comment: If the state you want back exists in a commit, use `git log` to find the sha1 you want, then `git reset --hard sha1` will bring your back there. Warning: this will destroy any uncommitted changes in your sandbox, so only do this if you really want to go back to the exact state described by that sha1.