# why git merge is not showing any difference

Tags: git, github

I have a branch called `dev` where I put some code for ejb changes and committed it to github, but the code didnt work, so to preserve the work, I created a branch out of `dev` called `ejb_change` and pushed to github.
I reverted the code in `dev` branch and committed more codes in `dev` branch and now I want to merge the `ejb_change` branch to `dev` branch.
But when I do a `git merge ejb_change`/ raise Pull Request, git is telling there are no change to merge. I am not able to understand

How do I put the `ejb_change` changes on top of current `dev` branch

Comment: Have u pushed your code to GitHub?

Comment: yes I have pushed my code to github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your *reverted* (like, used `git revert`), then ejb_branch is pointing to a revision that is part of the history of dev... and therefore if you try to merge ejb_change into dev, git will tell you that there's nothing to merge there.

If this is the case (I know this is the case because you already said so) then you could try either cherry-picking the original revision that you reverted (not sure if it will work, because the revision if part of the history of current branch)... or reverting the reversal revision... not elegant, but should work.

Comment: yes I agree with you...I reverted via `git revert` ,now how to put back the changes

Comment: Reverting the revert was a much easier process for me as there were multiple commits after the original revert..Now I am able to get the ejb_change branch changes on top of dev..Thanx for the idea

Comment: Cherry-picking the original or reverting the revert is essentially the same. The only real difference (besides which front end command you use) is that the revert itself might have already resolved issues that came up during the revert, so that reverting the revert might be easier than re-copying the original.

Answer (score 0):

when you say

> I reverted the code in dev branch and committed more codes

you mean that you commited some code undoing your changes? Or did you revert git history to a previous state? 
If you just commited a code undoing your changes, than the commits from ejb_change are already in dev and there's no merge.

Comment: I reverted via `git revert`, so it will be in the history ,I agree..now how to put back the ejb_change on top of dev in an easy way

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728093/how-do-i-un-revert-a-reverted-git-commit

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, also caused by a `revert`. The way I fixed it was by making a `git reset --hard <commit hash>` on `dev` branch with `commit hash` being the commit before the wrong code.
**A**->**B**->**C**, if B is the wrong code, C is it's revert, so use the hash of A.
This solution does require a `force push` once the `dev` history is changed because of the `reset`

> Watch out with the `--hard` as it will remove any changes after the selected commit, so do this only when you are sure you don't need the commits that will be reset

After that your pull request should work normally.

I guess there are better solutions but that's the one I know of.

Comment: I dont want to mess up the commit history..so reverting the revert was a much easier option for me `git revert <commit sha of the revert commit>`