# How do undo and stash a previous commit which is not the last?

Tags: git

I wonder if that's possible at all. I committed some changes, `commitA` and then some more and more... `commitB`, `commitC`. Now I realized I don't want `commitA` in the code for the moment, they need to be reviewed first.

So I need to undo that commit and stash it for review and commiting them again. Is there a straightforward way to do this? Or should I just revert those changes manually, commit the revert, then introduce the changes again and stash them?

Comment: How about using [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)?

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari I already pushed those commits.

Comment: You could make the changes in your local repo using rebase and then probably do force push

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari I'd rather not force push. I am trying to simply `git revert`, but how can I bring back the changes afterwards, so that I can stash them?

Comment: @dabadaba revert the revert? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728093/how-do-i-un-revert-a-reverted-git-commit

Comment: @sbat yes, but that straight out commits the revert. Rather, what I want is to have the changes back and then whatever I want with them (like stashing them).

Comment: @dabadaba git revert --no-commit ? :)

Answer (score 2):

If you've already shared the commit then yes, you're better off reverting it and recommitting later after review. If you haven't then you can just do an interactive rebase. Starting from a clean working directory:

```sh
git rebase -i <commitA>^
```

A text editor will open a file something like this:

```
pick <commitA> some commit message...
pick <commitB> blah blah...
pick <commitC> blah blah...
```

Change the "pick" by  to "edit", save, and quit the editor.  will be automatically checked out.

```
git reset HEAD^
git stash -u
git rebase --continue
```

The remaining commits will be replayed without .

Bear in mind if later commits rely on  then you'll get merge conflicts.

---

As pointed out by sbat in the comments; if you do decide to revert you don't need to manually undo your changes. You can use the `git revert` command.

Comment: I'd probably add to the response that revert does not have to be manual (as asked in the original question). https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert should be able to come to rescue if the commit is pushed.

Comment: After reverting, how do I get the changes back to the changelist so I can stash them?

Comment: I'd recommend checking out A and creating a new branch or tag on it rather than keeping it in the stash. You're less likely to lose it that way and you can review and apply/amend it later easily.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm..... i had already answered something like this... suppose some-branch is pointing to commitC

```
git checkout commitA
git reset --soft HEAD~
git stash save 'stashing commit A'
git rebase --onto HEAD commitA some-branch # get rid of commit A
```

Comment: Can you briefly explain what each command does? I get the gist of it, but how do you not lose the most recent commits after `commitA` when resetting the branch?

Comment: When you run the rebase, it will only apply revisions commitB and commitC (where some-branch is pointing to). CommitA will be discarded.

Comment: It will contain the changes that _used to be_ commitA, in other words, the changes between commitA~ and commitA

Comment: In the stash? Nope. Following my recipe, on the third command you are only stashing what is between commitA and its parent.

Comment: Yep, you're quite right. I totally misunderstood what you'd done.