# recovering deleted files git after revert

Tags: git, git-revert, recover

I have a new repository.  I added some files (a,b,c) via

```
git add .
git commit -m "x"
```

I realized file c was unnecessary so I looked for the last commit via

```
git log
```

with the commit id at hand I did

```
git revert commit-id
```

it started deleting all files
removing file a b c

How can I restore them?  I looked at the log and only the original commit x is in there.

I tried

```
git checkout HEAD^^ -- .
```

as per [How do I "un-revert" a reverted Git commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728093/how-do-i-un-revert-a-reverted-git-commit/8730046)

but I get "Invalid reference HEAD^^"

any ideas?

Comment: If you do a `git reflog` do you see the commit where you added the files?

Comment: @simon-pearson yes I see commit (HEAD->MASTER) HEAD@{0}: (initial): x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get the commit hash of the initial commit where you added the files by doing a `git reflog` (this is essentially a log of all of the recent HEADs of your branch - very useful for scenarios like this).
2. If you want to permanently go back to this commit and completely 'undo' your revert then do a `git reset --hard <commit-id>` replacing the hash with the hash of the initial commit where you added the files.  If you want to temporarily go back to this commit then do a `git checkout <commit-id>`.

Further reading on `git reflog`: http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
// It will reset your commit back to previous if its 2 commits back then use head~2 etc.
git reset head~1
```

Comment: I get ambiguous argument head~1 unknown revision or path in the working tree.    There's only 1 commit in the log.