# How to undo a git revert and go back to before that revert state?

Tags: git

I wanted to go to a certain stage of my commit. I `git revert 3a3a32` that commit but actually wanted to go back. How do I go back to that commit, after undoing the revert?

Comment: Do you mean `git reset --hard`?

Comment: @matt Please don't suggest reset without knowing A LOT more about the issue at hand. It is the main reason we have repeat questions here along the lines of "halp, I lost all my commits".

Comment: Do you have additional commits after the revert, with changes you want to keep

Comment: You can revert a reversion commit. It's just another commit, really.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I "un-revert" a reverted Git commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728093/how-do-i-un-revert-a-reverted-git-commit)

Comment: Love you guys all !! this is my first question asked.. People here are very helpful, I thought won't get help for may be days. @isherwood, no brother, not exactly that ans. after 'revert' i commited few times but didn't push. then reverte the revert commit. I exactly want undo all the mess and go back to the last that commit before reverting it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I agree of course, but I suspect that `git reset --hard` is exactly what the OP wants. I will of course remove the comment if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check `git reflog` command.

It displays list of your latest changes. Find position before your `git revert` and do `git checkout HEAD@{x}` where `x` is position returned from `git reflog`