# How to reset commit from another dev but keeping mine's?

Tags: git

I have this list of commits:

[image]

The first 2 commits are pretty well and works properly. 
But I need to remove those 3 commits below without affecting my work(first 2 commits).

Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe try using `Checkout` on the commit you wish to recover. You can then work on that copy and later `Commit` it once it is finished. Hope it helps.

Comment: See `git help revert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the commits you want are newer, you can't simply checkout to the commit because the previous commits will be there.  What I would suggest doing is the following.

1. Checkout to a new branch.
2. Reset to the last commit that you want (which would be the commit before `0e4e`)
3. On that new branch, run `git cherry-pick 54d8c0a2`, fix any conflicts, and then run `git cherry-pick d108639e`.

This will leave you with a branch that is `<commit before 0e4e> - 54d8c0a2  - d108639e`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git revert`.  Revert undoes changes from a specific commit, leaving all other changes untouched.  (Revert does not change the old commits themselves; it actually creates a new commit to make its changes.  That way, the commit you reverted is still in the repo's history if you ever need it.)  For example, run `git revert 5816058f` to revert their 'restore rest-defult' commit.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415565/how-to-revert-multiple-commits-as-part-of-a-single-commit) answer if you want to revert all 3 of their commits with a single commit.