# What is the proper way to re-do a reverted merge in git?

Tags: git

We recently had to revert a merge into the master branch due to a suspected bug it introduced.

Later, it turned out it wasn't a bug in my branch after all. But re-merging the same changes again turned out to be a challenge. Since git knew about the original merge, it (understandingly) stubbornly refused to merge the same changes into master again. I also didn't find a way to cleanly "replay" the changes I did into a new branch, probably because I merged changes from master into my branch now and then.

At the end, I made a diff on master from the state *after* the merge revert commit to the state *before* the said commit. So that this diff, when applied, would revert the changes from "merge revert" and thus would reapply my changes. I created a new branch based on the snapshot after merge revert, applied my diff onto it and had my new branch successfully merged into master.

All this worked well, but I wonder if there is a more straightforward way to reintroduce changes from a reverted merge. There were further commits and merges after the reverted merge, so simply restoring the repository from a backup etc. was not an option.

Comment: revert the reversal commit

Comment: This has been asked many, many times. For instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728093/how-do-i-un-revert-a-reverted-git-commit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354682/how-can-i-fix-a-reverted-git-commit

Answer (score 1):

Sergio's comment is right on target. However, if you *really* want to see the revisions applied *again*, there is a trick you can try...... You can reapply the revisions that made the original branch so that they become *new* revisions and then you can rebase them, or just merge them. Suppose that the original branch is called X and it's made up of 4 revisions (straight revisions, no merges):

```
git checkout X~4
git cherry-pick HEAD..X # reapply all 4 revisions so that they are brand new
git branch -f X # set X right here
git checkout the-target-branch
git merge X # this should work
```

You might also try rebasing the branch after the cherry-pick operation.