# Reverting a reverted merge in Git

Tags: git

I have a bit of a situation on the main branch in my repository.

A developer mistakingly pushed a PR from our develop branch directly into main and pushed to remote. We've applied policies so that this cannot happen again.

After this, we reversed this PR by utilising the 'Revert PR' feature in Azure DevOps, which created a branch, undid all the changes, and then merged it all back into main. So far so good.

In the meantime, we've also had to apply some hotfixes to the main branch. When attempting to roll these changes back up to develop, I've realised that the revert commit will also go back up, meaning we will lose changes in develop.

I've also now realised that when we do a PR from dev to main, these previously pushed changes will not be merged back down again.

How do I sort out the situation so that I do not lose the feature changes when merging hotfixes back into develop and also ensure that the feature comes back to main the next time we do a correct PR?

My assumption is that I need to revert the revert (git revert -m 1 ), but is there a better way?

Comment: If there are only a few commits, you can try cherry picking them again in the feature branch and then merging.

Comment: This is an extremely common question, please [search for existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+revert) such as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354682/how-can-i-fix-a-reverted-git-commit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078146/re-doing-a-reverted-merge-in-git https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728093/how-do-i-un-revert-a-reverted-git-commit

Answer (score 2):

You effectively reverted a merge, but that does not *erase* the merge. This is a classic situation. See https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt

As that article explains (in the words of Linus, who *wrote* Git in the first place, so he ought to know), if you revert a merge commit, you can never again merge the commits from the second parent, because they were already merged; the revert of the merge *commit* removes its *effects* on the first parent ("so far so good", as you say) , but it does not undo the *fact* of the merge, whose topology remains part of the history.

Your best bet is to construct that PR afresh, entirely from scratch, perhaps by cherry picking (or rebasing) its commits, so as to get the same effect using different commits. That will give you a new PR that you *can* merge all the way to main.

Answer (score 1):

Situation:

- `dev` was merged into `main` ("merge X")
- on `main`: "merge X" was reverted ("commit Y")

Suggestion:

- merge `main` back into `dev`
- then on `dev`: `git revert <commit Y>` (new "commit Z")
  Note: `-m 1` is **not** needed here, because the revert "commit Y" itself is just a regular commit, not a merge.

Result:

- Hotfixes from `main` are now also on `dev`
- `dev` has not lost (the once reverted) changes, because "commit Z" restored them
- If `dev` gets merged into `main` again, the once reverted changes will be applied again (because they now come from "commit Z")